# convert string to hexadecimal in R

Tags: python, r

I am trying to convert a string such as

```
 str <- 'KgHDRZ3N'
```

to hexadecimal. The function `as.hexmode()` returns an error

```
Error in as.hexmode("KgHDRZ3N") : 
  'x' cannot be coerced to class "hexmode"
```

are there any other functions I can use to achieve this?

I am trying to replicate what `.encode()` in python does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `charToRaw`

```r
charToRaw(str)
#> [1] 4b 67 48 44 52 5a 33 4e
```

Or if you want a character vector

```r
as.hexmode(as.numeric(charToRaw(str)))
#> [1] "4b" "67" "48" "44" "52" "5a" "33" "4e"
```

or if you want the "0x" prefix:

```r
paste0("0x", as.hexmode(as.numeric(charToRaw(str))))
#> [1] "0x4b" "0x67" "0x48" "0x44" "0x52" "0x5a" "0x33" "0x4e"
```